# The result of the code is always 0

Tags: python

Could anyone help please? The result of the code keeps showing 0. Where I went wrong? Thanks.

[image: What I tried to do]

```
import math
def m_t(r_w,r_l,t_w,t_l):
 a = r_w/t_w
 b = r_l/t_l
 c = math.ceil(a)
 d = math.ceil(b)
 if isinstance(a,int) & isinstance(b,int):
    return a*b
 elif isinstance(a,int) & isinstance(b,float):
    return a*d
 elif isinstance(a,float) & isinstance(b,int):
    return c*b
 else:
    return c*d

m_t(4,4,2,2)
```

Comment: Really? [I get `4`](https://ideone.com/WfGgpr).

Comment: If this is Python3 than `a` and `b` will always be `float`s.  You may be looking for the `float.is_integer` method.

Comment: What version of python are you using? `math.ceil` is different between 2 and 3. 3 can return an `int`.

Comment: I still get `4` [in Python 2](https://ideone.com/vleur9).

Comment: See [**`math.ceil`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.ceil) and [**`math.ceil`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.ceil) for Python 2 and 3 respectively.

Comment: this is version 3.6.5